# c# ProcessCmdKey overload, match generic combination

Tags: c#

On some control, I want ProcessCmdKey to return true if the keys pressed by the user were ALT and any letter of the alphabet.

I'm able to return true if the user presses Alt with the following code, but how can I add the condition of a letter also pressed ?

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
             if ((keyData & Keys.Alt) != 0) {
                  return true;
             }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code will not compile as is because there's no return value in the case of the test for Alt down is not true. Good practice with over-riding ProcessCmdKey is to call : return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData); when you have NOT handled the key event : see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx Henrik's answer below gives you the exact test you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ((keyData & Keys.Alt) != 0 && (keyData & Keys.KeyCode) >= Keys.A && (keyData & Keys.KeyCode) <= Keys.Z)
```

Comment: It seems to work great, thanks.
Can I ask what does keyData & Keys.KeyCode returns and why ?
Specifically what is Keys.KeyCode ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Keys.KeyCode is a bitmask where the least significant 16 bits are set. Right click on Keys and select "Go To Definition" to see it. Also, there is a bitmask Keys.Modifiers where the MSBs are set.

Answer (score 0):

xor should work:

```
 if ((keyData & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt & (keyData ^ Keys.Alt) != 0) {
      return true;
 }
```

Comment: "keys.Alt" should be "Keys.Alt" This will return 'true every time the alt key is pressed down, and will also return 'true any time any other key is pressed down while the alt key is down : in other words it does not filter based on "any letter of the alphabet."